# How to set FontFamily for cross platform in Xamarin Forms xaml file?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have style in code behind of abc.xaml.cs:

```
    Style labelHeadingStyle = new Style(typeof(Label))
    {
        Setters = {
            new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Black  },
            new Setter { Property = Label.FontFamilyProperty, Value = Device.OnPlatform (
                "SomeFont",
                "SomeFont",
                @"/Assets/Fonts/SomeFont.ttf#SomeFont"
            )  },
            new Setter { Property = Label.FontAttributesProperty, Value = FontAttributes.Bold  },
            new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 36 }
        }
    };
```

And in xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="labelHeadingStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How do i define `FontFamil` in xaml like i did in code behind (in C#) ?

Comment: What happened when you put the same Name in Value? Like <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Assets/Fonts/SomeFont.ttf#SomeFont" />

Comment: font doesn't get set. I have set the name per platform. As you can see for windows phone, i have to provide long name